# Create groups based on 10 day interval

Tags: sql, teradata, rank

I have the following data table

```
Animal  Immunization_Date
Cat     1/18/2017
Cat     1/27/2017
Cat     5/7/2017
Cat     5/12/2017
Dog     1/1/2017
Dog     1/5/2017
Dog     1/7/2017
Dog     3/25/2017
Dog     4/18/2017
```

I am trying to create a rank based on 10 day intervals by animal which would result in the following. (look for the first date of an animal and then any days within 10 days of that date assign a group of `1`. Then take the next date for the animal that is not assigned to `1` and assign it `2` and then assign `2` to any days within 10 days of that date etc...)

```
Animal  Immunization_Date   10_Day_Group_Rank
Cat     1/18/2017           1
Cat     1/27/2017           1
Cat     5/7/2017            2
Cat     5/12/2017           2
Dog     1/1/2017            1
Dog     1/5/2017            1
Dog     1/7/2017            1
Dog     3/25/2017           2
Dog     4/18/2017           3
```

I have been trying the following code but I cant seem to get the 10 day group to work.

```
Select
dt.Animal,
dt.Immunization_Date,
sum(dt.10_day_Group) over(partition dt.Animal order by dt.Immunization_Date rows unbounded preceding) as 10_day_Group --creates a running total that is also the group
from
(
Select
Animal,
Immunization_Date,
case when min(Immunization_Date) over (partition by Animal order by Immunization_Date) <=10 then 1 else 0 end as 10_Day_Group --Create intervals of 10 days
from Table_A
) as dt
```

I'm not really sure how to put together the 10 day grouping.

```
case when min(Immunization_Date) over (partition by Animal order by Immunization_Date) <=10 then 1 else 0 end as 10_Day_Group
```

I am able to do this in Excel with the following.  I know excel and SQL are different but I am hoping that if seen how it can be done in Excel if there is something that can be done in SQL.

The Excel data table looks like this(table starts in cell `A1`). (Note `Animal` needs to be sorted and `Immunization_Date` needs to be sorted in order for Excel formulas to work)

```
Animal  Immunization_Date   Dummy_1 10_Day_Group
Cat     1/18/2017       1/18/2017       1
Cat     1/27/2017       1/18/2017       1
Cat     5/7/2017        5/7/2017        2
Cat     5/12/2017       5/7/2017        2
Dog     1/1/2017        1/1/2017        1
Dog     1/5/2017        1/1/2017        1
Dog     1/7/2017        1/1/2017        1
Dog     3/25/2017       3/25/2017       2
Dog     4/18/2017       4/18/2017       3
```

The formula for `Dummy_1` is the following
`IFERROR(IF(AND(A2=A1,B2-C1<=10),C1,B2),B2)`

The formula for `10_Day_Group` is the following
`IFERROR(IF(AND(C2=C1,A2=A1),D1,IF(AND(A2=A1,C2<>C1),D1+1,1)),1)`

Comment: What if you had Cat, 1/29/2018 in the data?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  the `1/27/18` should be `1/27/17` which i updated in my op

Comment: Your business logic is unclear to me, and your example data feels inconsistent.  For example, a Dog was immunised on 18th April, nothing else was immunised 10 days before or after that date, but the 10 day ranking is 3?

Comment: Since there is no date 10 days before 4/18/17,so it would start a new 10 day interval and thus would be 3. So the 10 day interval for dog would start at 1/1/17 and then any days within 10 days of that would be considered `1`.  The next date available in the data set that is after that 10 day interval would be flagged as `2`.  In the dog example, that date is 3/25/17.

Comment: Okay, you're not ranking cats or dogs, you're "ranking" the windows of time themselves, separately for each animal?  Or, in my language, enumerating the windows of time?

Comment: I'm ranking the windows of time(window of time is 10 days) by animal, so i think what you wrote makes sense.

Comment: If I understand correctly you would group these dates as follows?  `{1, 9, 15, 22}` => `GRP1 = {1, 9}`, `GRP2 = {15, 22}`.  But if there was also an `11` in there then it would change to `GRP1 = {1, 9}`, `GRP2 = {11, 15}`, `GRP3 = {22}`?  *(I suspect that needs a recursive query, how many "10 day groups" do you expect per animal?  Worst case...)*

Comment: I can ***approximate*** my description without loops or recursion ***if*** you can allow the 10_day_boundaries to always be on 10 day increments.  so, if the lowest date for an animal is day 7 the boundaries are always `7-16`, `17-26`, `27-36`, `37-46`, etc.  Then I could take the values `{7, 16, 36, 37}` put them in to groups: `1=>{7,16}, 2={}, 3=>{36}, 4=>{37}`.  Then remove the empty groups: `1=>{7,16}, 2=>{36}, 3=>{37}`.  This would be dramatically cheaper/faster/simpler than the example I gave in the comment before this one...

Comment: I would change the `11` to `12` reason being that `11-1=10` thus fitting the 10 day window of time and change the `22` to `23` so it would be the following `{1,9,15,23}` => `GRP=1 {1,9}`, `GRP2 = {15,23}` but when a `12` is present it would become the following `GRP1 = {1,9}` , `GRP2 = {12,15}`, `GRP3 = {23}`

Comment: That's going to be messy, complicated, expensive and probably slow.  Do you ***need*** that, or would an approximation suffice?  *(Also, note, although `11-1=10`, there are 10 days in the group `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}`. Day 11 would therefor naturally be in a different group from day 1...)*

Comment: There's no way to get this result without some kind of loop. Either utilizing `WITH RECURSIVE` or a loop in a Stored Procedure. How many rows per animal and per group exist in average & max?

Comment: @dnoeth I believe I've solved this by manufacturing a period to cover the ten days, self joining on those periods, normalizing the results, then bouncing that back against the data to get a dense_rank. I may have overlooked something though as a nasty recursive CTE initially seemed like the only way to pull this off.

Comment: No word on whether an approximation is sufficient for you? Or how many 10-day-groupings you expect per animal?

Comment: The data set is random. Some animals can have 50+ instances while some will only have 1 instance.  I did add some more to my OP.  I can do it in Excel(I know it is different than SQL) but I was hoping to spark some more thoughts.

Comment: @AlmostThere - The difference is that you've solved it in a very linear manner.  You can't process any row until you've processed the preceeding row (Because the calculation uses the result from the preceeding row).  On a machine with multiple cores and multiple threads or pipelines this is very inefficient.  SQL scales well to multiple cores because it's a set based language, allowing the execution plan to break the problem in to many piece to process in parallel.  That's even more important on TeraData which is horizontally distributed.  Linear solutions are bad for SQL and TeraData...

Comment: That said, look at the comments on my answer.  There is a link to SQL Fiddle that uses Recursive Common Table Expressions.  That solution should be translatable to TeraData quite easily.  It is still less than ideal because the recursion is the linear loop, but it's less linear that some alternatives.  But that linearity will still mean that it can't make full use of multiple nodes/cores/threads/pipelines, and so is less than ideally performant.  But it does show that the full and exact solution is possible.

Comment: Finally, look at my approximations and test them.  These don't use recursion and so distribute much more readily.  Determine then whether the benefits of the exact solution are worth the cost-penalty when compared against the approximation.  That determination should also cause you to re-evaluate what you are trying to do and Why you are trying to do it.  You may be overly constraining yourself by how you define the 10-day-groups.  Other bucketting algorithms may be equally suited, or better suited.  Some algorithms are faster, some aim for minimal numbers of buckets, etc, etc.

Comment: The recursive solution provided by @MatBailie will work (with some slight modifcation), although it's not very efficient for a larger amount of data. But when you can process it in Excel it's not a large number of rows :-) When it's possible to use a Volatile Table it will be much more efficent.

Comment: @dnoeth - Feel free to add a TeraData specific Recursive solution?  *(I'm no TeraData expert and have no instance on which to test performance or behaviour.  In SQL Server the correlated sub-query approach is about as quick as I think the recursive approach will get, the SQL Server optimiser handles the correlation very well.)*

Comment: @MatBailie: Added a solution with a temporary table, mimicking cursor processing :-) Depending on the number of rows per animal/group this might be more efficient than finding the ranges first and then joining back.

Comment: No feedback on the answers, responses, etc, given to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MatBailie's recursive answer is quite nice, but performance will get worse when the number of rows per animal increases.

When the first CTE can be materialized in a Volatile Table it will lower resource usage (as Teradata's optimizer doesn't materialize this result, damn):

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE boundaries AS
(
  SELECT
    i.*, -- need to add the alias 
    (
      SELECT MIN(immunization_date)
        FROM immunizations
       WHERE animal             = i.animal
         AND immunization_date >= i.immunization_date + 10
    )
      AS next_boundary_date
  FROM
    immunizations   i
 )
WITH DATA 
UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX(animal, immunization_date)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

But when you can use temporary tables you can also go with simple recursion:

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE vt AS
 (
   SELECT
      animal, 
      immunization_date,
      Row_Number() -- add row number to simplify recursive processing
      Over (PARTITION BY animal
            ORDER BY immunization_date) AS rn
   FROM immunizations AS i
 )
WITH DATA 
UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX(animal, rn)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

WITH RECURSIVE cte AS
 (
   SELECT
      animal, immunization_date, rn,
      immunization_date+10 AS end_date, -- define the end of the range 
      1 AS grp -- SMALLINT = limited to 127 group, CAST to a larger INT for more groups
   FROM vt
   WHERE rn = 1 -- oldest row

   UNION ALL

   SELECT 
      vt.animal, vt.immunization_date, vt.rn,
      -- check if the current row's date is within the 10 day range
      -- otherwise increase the group number and define the new range end
      CASE WHEN vt.immunization_date < end_date THEN cte.end_date ELSE vt.immunization_date +10 END,
      CASE WHEN vt.immunization_date < end_date THEN cte.grp      ELSE cte.grp+1 END
   FROM cte
   JOIN vt
     ON vt.animal = cte.animal
    AND vt.rn = cte.rn+1
 )
SELECT *
FROM cte
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Comment: No idea about TeraData but the range search isn't done for every row in SQL Server *(or for the whole table on each iteration)*, it's done on demand *(so anything from 100% to 10% of the rows)*.  Using the ranges then minimises the depth the recursion needs to go to, again by a factor of *up to* 10.

Comment: @MatBailie: As Teradata is a massive parallel DBMS any processing which is not based on equality is not very efficient, i.e. *same animal* but *immunization_date >= i.immunization_date + 10*. Then it might be faster to process additional recursion levels (and *Some animals can have 50+ instances while some will only have 1 instance* is not a high number). Of course your solution should be quite efficient when the number of rows per group is high (Then I would just rewrite your Scalar Subquery to a solution based on OLAP functions which are very efficient on Teradat)

Comment: I couldn't think of an Analytical Function approach that could determine the next boundary...

Comment: Recursion without the correlated sub-query, but still using a range-search approach...  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5af35/32

Comment: This is a rewrite of the subquery to Analytical Functions: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6a068/1

Comment: @MatBailie: Your new fiddle is way more efficient on Teradata (quick test against a larger set), but fails to return the same result :-)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, i have been on vacation for the past week and a half.  I was able to use the recursion query which provided expected results.

Answer (score 1):

An approximation...

```
SELECT
  animal,
  immunization_date,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY animal
                         ORDER BY base_date,
                                  CAST(immunization_date - base_date AS INT) / 10
                    )
                      AS group_id
FROM
(  
  SELECT
    animal,
    immunization_date,
    MAX(
      CASE WHEN immunization_date < lagged_immunization_date + 10
           THEN NULL
           ELSE immunization_date
      END
    )
      OVER (PARTITION BY animal
                ORDER BY immunization_date
                    ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
           )
             AS base_date
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      animal,
      immunization_date,
      LAG(immunization_date) OVER (PARTITION BY animal
                                       ORDER BY immunization_date
                                  )
                                    AS lagged_immunization_date
    FROM
      yourData
  )
    lagged_dates
)
  base_dated
```

SQLFiddle doesn't have TeraData but the above code should work in TeraData ***and*** SQL Server...  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/68260/1

Comment: A crude SQL Server recursive answer : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/55362/1

Answer (score 0):

We can take advantage of Teradata's PERIOD data type and its related functions to help solve this without getting too complicated.

This is close. Not exact, but close:

```
WITH ta_period AS
(
        SELECT
            PERIOD(immunization_date - INTERVAL '10' DAY, immunization_date) AS periodbucket,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY animal ORDER BY immunization_date) AS animal_row,
            table_a.animal,
            table_a.immunization_date
        FROM table_a
)
,cal_buckets AS
(

    SELECT calendar_dateFROM Sys_Calendar."CALENDAR" cal
    WHERE calendar_date >= (SELECT MIN(immunization_date) FROM table_a)
        AND calendar_date <= (SELECT MAX(immunization_date) FROM table_a)
)
SELECT
    TA.animal,
    TA.immunization_date,
    cal_buckets.bucket,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ta.animal ORDER BY ta_normal.periodbucket, cal_buckets.bucket ) AS ten_day_bucket
FROM
    (
        SELECT NORMALIZE    
            ta_period.animal,   
            ta_period.periodbucket P_INTERSECT ta_period.periodbucket AS periodbucket
        FROM ta_period LEFT OUTER JOIN ta_period ta_period2 
            ON ta_period.periodbucket CONTAINS ta_period2.immunization_date
                AND ta_period.animal = ta_period2.animal
                AND ta_period.animal_row <> ta_period2.animal_row   
    ) ta_normal
    INNER JOIN ta_period ta ON
        ta_normal.animal = ta.animal
        AND ta_normal.periodbucket P_INTERSECT ta.periodbucket IS NOT NULL
    INNER JOIN cal_buckets ON
        ta.immunization_date = cal_buckets.calendar_date;
```

Comment: *(I can't test this, so I apologise if I'm in error, and for the notation...)*

With the "dates" `1, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24`...

The join will yield `1:{NULL}, 9:{1}, 12:{9}, 15:{9, 12}, 18:{9, 12, 15}, 21:{12, 15, 18}, 23:{15, 18, 21}`.

The `COALESCE(MIN(),SELF)` will yield `1:{1}, 9:{1}, 12:{9}, 15:{9}, 18:{9}, 21:{12}, 23:{15}`.

The `DENSE_RANK()` will yield `1:{1}, 9:{1}, 12:{2}, 15:{2}, 18:{2}, 21:{3}, 23:{4}`.

Thus, date 24 is in group 4 when it should be in group 3.

Comment: A shorter example that's easier to work out by hand, with the "dates" `1, 7, 13, 20`...

The join will yield `1:{NULL}, 7:{1}, 13:{7}, 20:{13}`.

The `COALESCE(MIN(),SELF)` will yield `1:{1}, 7:{1}, 13:{7}, 20:{13}`.

The `DENSE_RANK()` will yield `1:{1}, 7:{1}, 13:{2}, 20:{3}`.

Thus, date 20 is in group 3 when it should be in group 2.

Comment: I honestly believe that the best bet here is to have fixed 10 day "windows" based on the min value of the sequence.  `1, 9, 19, 28, 31, 47, 56` would then go in to buckets of `{1-10} {11-20} {21-30} {31-40} {41-50} {51-60}` and so give groups of `{1, 9}`, `{19}`, `{28}`, `{31}`, `{47}`, `{56}`.  That could then be "improved" by restarting the boundaries at rows where the are no entries in the preceding 9 days.  The buckets would then be `{1-10} {19-28} {29-38} {47-56}` and so give groups of `{1, 9}`, `{19, 28}`, `{31}`, `{47, 56}`.  Anything much more sophisticated would need a loop...

Comment: I'm having a hard time following your notation, but I appreciate how nicely it fits in a comment! I disagree with your idea of using buckets (I explored that as well, using the begin date for each animal as the start point for the bucketing and using sys_calendar.calendar to build the buckets). It was a strange solution and I scrapped it for two reasons: 1. It's not OPs requirements. 2. I was 3 subqueries deep and still didn't have a nice result. I believe this solution matches OP's intent and it's pretty concise. It should perform well on a large data set as well.

Comment: I'm getting your notation now. I see how this wouldn't be a fit for something like `1,5,12` which should all yield `1`. BAck to the drawing board! (Unfortunately it's looking more likely that a recursive CTE would be a good, and expensive, fit).

Comment: @MatBailie I've updated the code to deal with the scenarios you have listed here. I was kicking around the idea of period intersecting the self join and normalizing the result to generate the buckets and that worked out pretty well. Got rid of the nested `dense_rank() over (coalesce(min()))` as a result. Much less confusing now. Teradata's `NORMALIZE` is some scary powerful stuff.

Comment: What do you get when you use the dates `1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 29`?  *(All of Jan 2017, for example...)*

Comment: In that case, all 1s. Is that not what would be expected since all of these occur within 10 days of each other. Or is that where the buckets are to come in to play?

Comment: As I understand it, the OP would want `{1, 5, 9}`, `{13, 17, 21}`, `{25, 29}`.  The first day is `1` so the first group is `1-10`, the next value is `13` so the second group is `13-22`, the next value is `25`, so the third group is `25-34`.

Comment: This is just the damndest set of requirements there ever was.

Comment: It's trying to batch the data into groups where the groups are no more than 10 days wide.  Whether it achieves what the OP thinks it does, that's another question.  It probably seems like a way to get the fewest number of buckets or something, but it's not quite that *(at least not for all possible data)*.  All I can tell is what the OP described, but not why the OP wants that ;)

Comment: I just added a bit that buckets into 10 day groups where the 10 day groups start at the min(immunization_date) of the incoming table. I agree, that doesn't exactly satisfy OP's requirements. No doubt the bucketing logic in the cal_buckets CTE I've added could be improved to take into account the `animal` in the incoming data.I'm not my way out though and didn't feel like tinkering with it much deeper than that, but I feel like this is the right direction. I'll be interested to see what you come up with! It's been a fun puzzle to solve.

Comment: Just a recursive CTE; start with the min date, then the min date where date >= previous_min + 10, blah, blah.  Other than that it would be the approximation I described above.  group_id = (date - min_date) / 10 *(then use `dense_rank()` to remove gaps)*, with an "improvement" of re-starting the search at any date with a gap of more than 10 days preceding it.